# Merge Pull Requests looking ugly / is it practicable?

Tags: git

currently we are using git and atlassin stash. at the moment our master branch is a whole bunch of pull request. every developer makes a pull request that gets pulled into the master branch.
is this even practicable?
I mean our history of master always has commits like this:

```
Christian Schmitt committed 1235 mins ago
Merge pull request #1 in master from develop to master

* commit '12356':
Fixed in #Number
Commit Message
```

Is this a good behavior or how could we improve this?
What are the best ways to have a clean git history?
Is the git push-pull technique really good, since i think the commits looking ugly somehow.
maybe this is just my point of view.

What do you guys do?

Comment: Is this a good way in doing pull requests from a remote branch to master?

Answer (score 0):

This is a practicable git workflow.

Many projects do this.

This retains the author's commit without modification.

From the revision graph, the author knows his commit is merged by the maintainer without any modification, though you can see the merge lanes on the revision graph.

If the maintainer wish to modify the commit, cherry-pick/rebase is used. No message "merge ... from xxx" is created. No merge point is shown on the revision graph.

Comment: currently Atlassian Stash don't support a git rebase workflow.
so i still need to deal with pull request commits.